# Seed a data pair to rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Im attempting to seed a :name, :date pair to a table in my rails app (via seed.rd)... Not quite sure how to do this.. My attempt below:

```
[[ "New Years Day", 2013/01/01 ][ "Easter", 2013/03/31]].each do |holiday|
  Holiday.create!({:name, :date => holiday})
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
[{ :name => "New Years Day", :date => "2013/01/01" },{ :name => "Easter", :date => "2013/03/31"}].each do |holiday|
  Holiday.create!(holiday)
end
```

Option 2:

```
[[ "New Years Day", "2013/01/01" ],[ "Easter", "2013/03/31"]].each do |holiday|
  Holiday.create!({:name => holiday[0], :date => holiday[1]})
end
```

Option 3 (actually not a good one, since it gets dirty when you go beyond just a name and a date):

```
{ "New Years Day" => "2013/01/01" , "Easter" => "2013/03/31"}.each do |holiday|
  Holiday.create!({:name => holiday.first, :date => holiday.second})
end
```